# PowerShell Copy-Item what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Given the dir structure:

```
x\Code
x\Script\Backup.ps1
```

Backup.ps1 contains:

```
$BackupDirectoy       = "..\Backup"
$CodeDirectory        = "..\Code"

function BackupCurrentVersion()
{
  New-Item $BackupDirectoy -type directory -force
  Copy-Item $CodeDirectory -destination $BackupDirectory -recurse
}

BackupCurrentVersion
```

I'm doing something wrong because Code gets copied in x\Script\Code instead of x\Backup\Code

What is the problem?

Comment: Haha. Just found the problem. It's a typo "BackupDirectoy" - forgot an 'r'. Damn. I've spent 2 hours on this problem

Comment: You can avoid these kinds of problems by using Set-StrictMode cmdlet at the start of your script. It will not let you use any variables you have not declared (it would have caught this error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$BackupDirectoy       = "..\Backup"
$CodeDirectory        = "..\Code"
```

These paths are going to be relative to the current dir your prompt is sitting in when you run the script.  I suspect you don't want that but want to run relative to where the *script* is located.  Try this if this is the case:

```
$ScriptDir      = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
$BackupDirectoy = "$ScriptDir\..\Backup"
$CodeDirectory  = "$ScriptDir\..\Code"
```

Comment: Actually I want the paths to be relative to script location. The current dir in PowerShell is set to x\Script